# Accessing state change from redux inside props, state successfully changes but props for that object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

first questioner here!

I'm new to React and find it confusing to manage state with redux. From the redux-logger output, it seems that I am successfully changing the redux state regarding a user sign-in but I don't really know how to set it to props, and as such, I'm getting an undefined value for currentUser (which is the prop I want to manage across all my pages). I'm using both withRouter and Redux in an effort to pass user properties to app.js.

It starts with an API call to the backend to see if the user can login, if success then returns an object {isAdmin: "", uId: ""}.

```js
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { setCurrentUser } from "../../redux/user/user-actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// sign-in.jsx
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

onSubmitClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("/api/login", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: "",
        password: "",
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((user) => {
        if (user.error) {
          this.setState({ error: user.error });
        } else {
          // Set the user in redux too:
          this.props.dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
          // Redirect to main page after login
          this.props.history.push({
            pathname: "/",
            search: "?uid=" + user.key + "?admin=" + user.admin,
            state: { userId: user.key, isAdmin: user.admin },
          });
        }
      });
};

render() {
    return (...)
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Login));
```

The line with code: `this.props.dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));` successfully changed the state but not the props value.

Here is the redux stuff:

```js
// user-actions.js --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export const setCurrentUser = (user) => ({
  type: "SET_CURRENT_USER",
  payload: user,
});


// user-reducer.js --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The initial state is basically a null user (ID)
const initialState = {
  user: null,
};

/*
This is essentially a function that takes the current state
and action as an argument and returns a new state result. 
i.e. (state, action) => newState
*/
const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  // Conditional for the current action type
  if (action.type.localeCompare("SET_CURRENT_USER") === 0) {
    // Return a new state object
    return {
      // Which has the existing data but also..
      ...state,
      // The new user object (just an ID at this point)
      user: action.payload,
    };
  } else {
    // Otherwise we return the state unchanged
    // (usually when the reducer doesnt pick up the certain action)
    return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer; 


// store.js --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";


/*
Useful for debugging redux --> logger 
Is a logger middleware that console.logs the actions fired and change of state
*/
import logger from "redux-logger";

import rootReducer from "./root-reducer";

const middlewares = [logger];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export default store;

// root-reducer.js --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import userReducer from "./user/user-reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
});
```

And finally, the App.js relevant code

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...props,
      u_id: null,
    };
  }
  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { setCurrentUser } = this.props;[enter image description here][1]
    const userState = this.props.location;
    console.log(this.props);
    // Make sure that state for a user isnt undefined
    if (userState.state) {
      this.unsubscribeFromAuth = true;
      const user = userState.state.userId;
      this.props.dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
    }
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = false;
  }

  render() {
     return (...)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.currentUser,
});

//Access the state and dispatch function from our store
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
  dispatch,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(App));
```

Console output with redux-logger:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9JyV.png

- As you can see, currentUser is undefined but all props in the location are there, I'm probably making some really dumb mistake when setting currentUser with the `setCurrentUser` action, both in the login and then again in the componentDidMount in the `app.jsx`
- I'll add more detail upon request

Any help would be appreciated GREATLY! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the user in redux under `user` but you are trying to access it in the mapStateToPRops via currentUser:

`const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ currentUser: state.currentUser, });`

Change it to `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ currentUser: state.user, });`

and it should work.

Also this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
  dispatch,
});
```

is equivalente to:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = ({
 setCurrentUser
});
```

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object

Comment: It works! Thanks so much, such a silly mistake :P